# Video Synthesis with Transfer Learning on Encoder

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder, encoder, transfer-learning

I am running into a very odd error with Pytorch in which I am synthesizing video using the following model. I am trying to apply transfer learning to the encoder only. To do this I have frozen the weights of the the generator with `requires_grad = False` and have done the opposite for the encoder.

Here is my model:

```
autoencoder(
  (generator): VideoGenerator(
    (recurrent): GRUCell(10, 10)
    (main): Sequential(
      (0): ConvTranspose2d(64, 512, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ReLU(inplace)
      (3): ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (4): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (5): ReLU(inplace)
      (6): ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (7): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (8): ReLU(inplace)
      (9): ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (10): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (11): ReLU(inplace)
      (12): ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (13): Tanh()
    )
  )
  (encoder): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (3): ReLU(inplace)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (5): ReLU(inplace)
    (6): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (7): ReLU(inplace)
    (8): Conv2d(512, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
  )
)
```

Here is the output when I cycle through the params.requires_grad

```
*** encoder ***
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 False
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 False
11 False
12 False
13 False
14 False
15 False
16 False
17 False
*** generator ***
18 True
19 True
20 True
21 True
22 True
```

But this gives a runtime error as follows:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-73fe2d39b929> in on_wl_clicked(b)
     87 #         print(model)
     88 
---> 89         loss.backward()
     90 
     91 #         show_state("AFTER BACKWARD STEP:", model)

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    100                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    101         """
--> 102         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    103 
    104     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     91 
     92 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Oddly, when I set the 0th tensor requires_grad = True (see below), it runs but fails to converge

```
*** encoder ***
1 True
2 False
3 False
4 False
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 False
11 False
12 False
13 False
14 False
15 False
16 False
17 False
*** generator ***
18 True
19 True
20 True
21 True
22 True
```

Any ideas of where this error is originating from or how to remediate it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the loss tensor inherits its auto_grad from the top of the chain-rule, and since the first tensor had `requires_grad = False`, the loss tensor was also false.

The fix was simple, add the line

```
loss.requires_grad = True 
loss.backward()
```

An alternative solution was just to chnage the optimizer like so

```
# optimizer = optim.Adam(param = model.parameters(), lr = lr)
optimizer = optim.Adam(param = model.encoder.parameters(), lr = lr)
```